# How to set up Android API version in react native project?

Tags: react-native

I used to develop Android apps in Android studio. I'm trying to play with react native and expo in VS. I used to set up the minimum API to 16 in the Bundle because more than 95% of the users support this API. I'm trying to figure out how to do in the react native or if it is even possible. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

Expo is a good solution however it has some limitations such as:

```
The minimum supported OS versions are Android 5+ and iOS 10+
If you need to support older versions, you will not be able to use the managed workflow.
```

Source: https://docs.expo.io/introduction/why-not-expo/

However in a bare `react-native` application you could target `version 4.1` and above.

Source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native#-requirements

Answer (score 0):

You do it same way you did it before.
Change minSdkVersion in PROJECT_DIR/android/build.gradle